# How to find longitude and latitude for multiple addresses

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude

I have a lots of adresses and want to find easier way to find their longitude and latitude?

Have anybody here some idea?

EDIT:
I do not want to find it in the app. I just need to convert them.

Thank you

Comment: "Easier" than what? What ideas have you already tried? Have you looked into google geocoding api?

Answer (score 3):

You require to use the **forward geocoding API** from Google to get the lat/Log from address.

[iPad/iPhone forward geocoding API using Google gecoding service](http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/)

Comment: thank for you response. but I only want to convert list of adresses to the longitude and latitude and add it to the plist.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Maps and search for the address. When you find it, look for the "copy link" box and grab the URL from there. Paste it into a text editor and look for the part that says &ll=. This is the latitude-longitude pair.